# Minimize the heights

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

Given a list of integers, denoting heights of `N` towers, and a positive integer `K`, I need to modify the height of each tower, either by increasing or decreasing it by `K` only once.

After modification, the resulting height should be a non-negative integer.
The goal is to find the possible minimum difference of the height of shortest and longest towers after the modification.

I've written the following code to solve this problem, but it doesn't work. I'd appreciate any ideas.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc = int(input())
    while tc > 0:
        k = int(input())
        n = int(input())
        arr = list(map(int,    
input().strip().split()))
        ob = Solution()
        ans = ob.getMinDiff(arr, n, k)
        print(ans)
        tc -= 1


class Solution:
    def getMinDiff(self, arr, n, k):
        arr.sort()
    
        for i in range(0,n):
            if(arr[i]<k):
                arr[i]=arr[i]+k
            else:
                arr[i]=arr[i]-k
        
    
        arr.sort()
        return arr[n-1]-arr[0]
```

Comment: Could you please specify which cases your code does not succeed in. Please provide the code of the tests. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some link of problem or platform where I can test my solution

Comment: Your code always subtracts `k` if the value is greater than `k`. This will fail for inputs like `[98, 102], k=1`. The best solution is `[99, 101]`, yours will compute `[97, 101]`.

Comment: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/minimize-the-heights3351/1

Comment: can anyone give the correct code for this answer or please correct my code where I have made mistake